# Where does OS X store the list of disabled fonts?

Tags: font, font-book

I am using Font Book a lot and manage my fonts with it. Now, I want to back up all my settings.

I found my collections in ~/Library/Font Collections

But where does OS X store which fonts are disabled? I want to copy this "list" and move it to my new mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where the list of disabled fonts is stored depends on the version of OS X you are using.

First of all, the `~/Library/Fonts Disabled/` and `/Library/Fonts Disabled` have never been used by Apple for the handling of disabled fonts; rather, fonts are simply deactivated in place: there's no need to move them out of the /Fonts/ folder in order to deactivate them. Those folders are most likely created by the Microsoft Office installer for Mac, or some other application installer.

As I mentioned, where the list of deactivated fonts is stored depends on the version of OS X you're using.

OS X 10.3: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ATS.plist` stores a list of file paths to the fonts which have been disabled in Font Book.

OS X 10.4 — 10.6: The enabled or disabled state of a particular font is stored within the font cache files themselves. There is no saved external record (like the preference file used in 10.3) of which fonts were disabled.

In OS X 10.7.x and later, while the enabled or disabled state of a particular font is still stored within the font cache files themselves, an external record of which fonts were disabled is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.FontRegistry.user.plist`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have `Fonts Disabled` folders either, but the list of disabled fonts is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.FontRegistry.user.plist`. If you copy it to another computer, run `sudo atsutil databases -remove; atsutil server -shutdown` to apply the changes.

Comment: I didn't realize that the '~/Library/Fonts Disabled' and '/Library/Fonts Disabled' folders that I noted in my post are specifically for fonts used by Microsoft Office for Mac 2008/2011. Sorry for the confusion, I've deleted my post.